# Hudson: Running all jobs in a view by pressing one button

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

Is there a way to run all jobs in one hudson's view by pressing just one button? Thanks.

Comment: I really hope there's an answer to this, it drives me nuts too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: here is the solution**

Edit your view's description and paste this code into it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function triggerBuilds(obj){
    obj.responseText.evalJSON()['jobs'].each(
            function(i){
                new Ajax.Request(i['url']+'build',{method:'GET'});
            }
    );
}

function buildAll(){
    new Ajax.Request(
            document.URL.replace(/[\W]+$/,'') + '/api/json',
            {
                onSuccess : triggerBuilds,
                method : 'GET'
            }
    );
}

//-->
</script>
<a href="javascript:buildAll();void(0)">Build all Jobs in this view</a>
```

This will create a link that builds all jobs in the current view using hudson's JSON api. (Only works from the view, if you want to use it from somewhere else you have to change the relative URLs).

(this solution relies on prototype which is present in current versions of hudson, but I don't know how long it has been present, so this may not work for older versions)

or create a bookmarklet for this URL:

```
javascript:var%20f=function(obj){obj.responseText.evalJSON()['jobs'].each(function(i){new%20Ajax.Request(i['url']+'build',{method:'GET'});});};new%20Ajax.Request(document.URL.replace(/[\W]+$/,'')+'/api/json',{onSuccess:f,method:'GET'});void(0)
```

in your bookmark menu and execute it on any hudson view you like

---

Edit: I have [elaborated on this answer on my weblog](http://mostlymagic.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/using-prototype-ajax-in-hudson/).

Comment: could you please elaborate? what browser, what error message do you get, if any? (for me it works fine in firefox, ie and safari on several different views in several different hudson installations)

Comment: we use chrome and firefox. it doesnt give me any error messages.

Comment: do you have the rights to execute the hudson api? (try `http://yourhudson/view/yourview/api` ). Is the url of the view of the form `http://yourhudson/view/yourview/` ? Is javascript turned on?

Comment: don't think that's it, I am using 1.355 on one machine where it works, and both the api and prototype have been in hudson for ages. Try the debug version from my edited post. Do you see anything?

Comment: I get this:

Job started: bond_ua_win_together_ua_email

Job started: bond_ua_win_together_ua_friends

Job started: bond_ua_win_together_ua_kladr

but actually jobs dont start

Comment: when i hit urls in response it gives me error because urls there represented as IP.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a parent Job and use it to launch all the children job (maven jobs with a dependency tree).

Combined with the [Join Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Join+Plugin), you can even set a Job when all previous jobs are completed.

Comment: Dependencies are the only way I can think off, too. Otherwise check your jobs if they can be triggered by an SCM change or to run them periodically (like once a day).